# Pandas + Numpy ndarray inside HDF5?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, hdf5

I'm trying to serialize a Pandas DataFrame containing 2D (or 3D) Numpy `ndarray`:

This fails:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
store = pd.HDFStore("store.h5")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])
df.loc['t1'] = {'a': np.random.rand(100, 100), 'b': np.random.rand(2000)}
store.append('test', df)
store.close()
```

with

> TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [a] because its data contents are not [string] but [mixed] object dtype

Is there a way to use Pandas + Numpy `ndarray` + serialization with HDF5?

Context: Here is what I want to achieve: [100GB data store: Pandas dataframe of numpy ndarrays: loading only a small part + avoid rewriting the whole file when doing small modifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72742843/100gb-data-store-pandas-dataframe-of-numpy-ndarrays-loading-only-a-small-part), [Data structure for sparse n-dimensional array / tensor such A[0, :, :] and A[1, :, :] can have different shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72733385/data-structure-for-sparse-n-dimensional-array-tensor-such-a0-and-a1), [N-dimensional array data store (with labeled indexing)](https://afewthingz.com/ndarraydatastore)
.

Comment: `df.loc[index] = row` does not assign dtypes correctly. Use the DataFrame constructor directly and assign dtypes. Verify/print dtypes before storing, for debugging.

Comment: `h5py` can store numpy arrays, but the pandas stire uses a `tables` interface.  I haven't used it, but it looks like it has problems with a frame that has object dtype columns that contains things like arrays.  Study its docs.